# Document path odoo 8

Tags: action, odoo-8, dms

I have created a kanban view for Document management system to show folders and files. To do this i have created an action. Each time i click on  folder the document path above the save button displays the action name instead folder name. i need to display the folder name please help!!
  Code:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_ams_document_file_directory_form1">
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">document.directory</field>
        <field name="name">Folder</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id"
            ref="3e_apartment_management.view_document_sub_directory_kanban" />
        <field name="domain">[('parent_id','=',active_id)]</field>
        <field name="context">{'parent_id':active_id}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                This folder is empty.
            </p>
            <p>
                Click on 'Create' button to add new folder.
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Attached screen shots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the name_get method. This will set the name that will be displayed on top of the page.

In the following code `"%s" % (record.name)` can be changed to your own value or method that returns the value for the record

**example old api**

```
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return [(record.id, "%s" % (record.name))
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)]
```

**example new api**

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    return [(record.id, "%s" % (record.name))
            for record in self]
```

Comment: thank you programme... now i getting an error "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Comment: Thanks for your update,  i just added above code in py file but nothing happen... pls help

Comment: No error messages.  If i click on 'Documents' the path on top should be 'Documents' structure/ Documents'. now it shows 'Documents' structure/Folder', the 'Folder' is name of an action.

Comment: Odoo creates that path using java script in web module named as view.js 
`

Comment: well you should edit the code so it shows you the correct path. I'd suggest that you create a new method to find that path. This method is just to change that text